# How to fix the ad-list working, but the adult list is not?

Tags: windows, batch-file, hosts

I have this web-blocking program called HackeyBlock, it blocks sites by adding rules that refer to 127.0.0.0.1, but of the 5 lists it supports, two do not seem to be written to the file.

I checked for typo's and even rewrote my code for the adult and privacy list based on the working ad list, but it still does not work.

This is the code for the working ad list:

```
:Hackeyadblock
del /f /q Hackey-adlist.txt
powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Marnix0810/HackeyBlock-Blocking-lists/master/hackey-adlist.txt', 'Hackey-adlist.txt') }"
for /F "eol=; tokens=*" %%A in (Hackey-adlist.txt) do (
ECHO # HackeyBlock Rule >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
ECHO 127.0.0.1 %%A >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
cls
echo added %%A to blocklist.
set /a blockedsitescounter+=1
)
exit /b
```

The privacy list:

```
:Hackeyprivacy
del /f /q Hackey-privacy.txt
powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Marnix0810/HackeyBlock-Blocking-lists/master/hackey-privacy.txt', 'Hackey-privacy.txt') }"
for /F "eol=; tokens=*" %%A in (Hackey-privacy.txt) do (
ECHO # HackeyPrivacy Blocking Rule >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
ECHO 127.0.0.1 %%A >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
cls
echo added %%A to blocklist.
set /a blockedsitescounter+=1
)
exit /b
```

And the adult content list:

```
:Hackeyadultblock
del /f /q Hackey-adlist.txt
powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Marnix0810/HackeyBlock-Blocking-lists/master/Adult-content-host-list.txt', 'Hackey-adultlist.txt') }"
for /F "eol=; tokens=*" %%A in (Hackey-adultlist.txt) do (
ECHO # Hackey rule: this site hosts adult content >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
ECHO 127.0.0.1 %%A >> "%temp%\hosts.edit.tmp"
cls
echo added %%A to blocklist.
set /a blockedsitescounter+=1
)
exit /b
```

after the selected lists are merged to %temp%\hosts.edit.tmp they are copied to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

also, this is a link to the full script on Github: https://github.com/Marnix0810/HackeyBlock-Windows/blob/master/CODE/hackeyblock.cmd

The rules for privacy and adult lists should be added too. But instead they are not added to the hosts file at all, while the ad-list rules are.

EDIT: it seems like the privacy list works now that I updated the link, but the adult-content list is still a mystery.

Comment: Is there any error message that appears? If so, copy and paste it into the question. Have you commented out or removed `ECHO OFF` so that you can see what is really being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of one method I'd try, *(if I was happy to use this ancient method of site blocking)*.

```bat
(
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%A In ("Hackey-adultlist.txt") Do (
        Echo # Hackey rule: this site hosts adult content
        Set /P "=127.0.0.1 %%A" < NUL
        Echo=
        ClS
        Echo Added %%A to blocklist > CON
        Set /A blockedsitescounter +=1
    )
) >> "%TEMP%\hosts.edit.tmp"
```